# Given a select statement how do i subselect more?

Tags: mysql

The following select statement gives me a table with overtime greater than 80:

```
SELECT empid,overtime FROM(SELECT empid, IF(SUM(slength)>80,SUM(slength)-80,0) 
as 'overtime' from schedule_2 group by empid) as t
where overtime >0;
```

[![Output][1]][1]

Now I want to join the empid with another table(t3) where I have to concatenate the first name and last name and then join it to the above table.

[![This table][2]][2]

I cant seem to figure out how to join both these select statement and keep running into errors

Comment: Maybe have a look at using common table expressions, define one for each table and then use a UNION or some kind of JOIN in order to put them together. Then select from the joint results

Comment: @sjdm That would only be an option if the OP were using MySQL 8+, or maybe certain versions of MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

use your query as a sub-query and join with table t3 ans use `concat` function

```
select t1.empid,
concat(t3.firstname,t3.lastname) as name,
t1.overtime from    
(
select * from
(
SELECT empid, IF(SUM(slength)>80,SUM(slength)-80,0) 
as overtime from schedule_2 group by empid
) as t
where overtime >0
) as t1 join t3 on t1.empid=t3.empid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below using join with employees_2 table

```
SELECT t.empid,overtime,concat(firstname,' ',lastname) as empname
FROM
(SELECT empid, IF(SUM(slength)>80,SUM(slength)-80,0) 
as 'overtime' from schedule_2 group by empid) as t
inner join employees_2 t1 on t.empid=t1.empid
where overtime >0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select empid, fullName, overtime
from (
    SELECT empid,
           overtime 
    FROM (
        SELECT empid, 
               IF(SUM(slength)>80,SUM(slength)-80,0) as overtime
        from schedule_2 group by empid
    ) as t where overtime > 0
) a join (
    select concat(firstName, ' ', lastName) fullName, 
           empid 
    from employees_2
) b on a.empid = b.empid
```